How to position elements using CGContext so that its properly shown in SwiftUI view
I am trying to use ImageRenderer to print a simple table in PDF but I am quite struggling.
I am quite confused about positioning and measures here.
Here is the code:
import SwiftUI

struct Stat: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: String
    let totalMatches: Int
    let points: Int
}


struct GridView: View {
    let stats: [Stat]

    var body: some View {
        Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
            GridRow(alignment: .center) {
                Text("ID")
                Text("Matches")
                Text("Points")
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .bold()
                .font(.headline)
                .background(.pink)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

            ForEach(Array(stats.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (index, stat) in
                GridRow(alignment: .center) {
                    Text(stat.id)
                    Text(stat.totalMatches, format: .number)
                    Text(stat.points, format: .number)
                }.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            }
        }
        .background(.purple.opacity(0.2))
    }
}


struct ExportImagesView: View {
    @State private var image = Image(systemName: "heart")

    private let pages = ["Page1"]
    private let stats = [
        Stat(id: UUID().uuidString, totalMatches: 4, points: 12),
        Stat(id: UUID().uuidString, totalMatches: 9, points: 31),
        Stat(id: UUID().uuidString, totalMatches: 4, points: 14),
        Stat(id: UUID().uuidString, totalMatches: 1, points: 0),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {

            image
            Divider()
            HStack {
                ShareLink("Export", item: render())
                Spacer()
                Button {
                    render()
                } label: {
                    Text("Render")
                }
            }.padding()

        }
    }

    @MainActor 
    @discardableResult
    func render() -> URL {

        let url = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "output.pdf")

        var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,  width: 595.2, height: 841.8)

        guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, nil) else {
            return url
        }

        for _ in pages {
            pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
            let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: GridView(stats: stats))
            renderer.render { size, context in context(pdf)}
            pdf.endPDFPage()

        }

        pdf.closePDF()

        if let cgImage =  pdf.makeImage() {

            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
        }

        return url
    }
}



struct ExportImagesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExportImagesView()
    }
}

There are two main issues. First is, I can't make a preview of a pdf. I tried to use makeImage() method on CGContext but it fails.
Also, there is more issues with positioning of a content before printing. Here is how pdf looks
:
Since CGContext uses a different coordinate system than SwiftUI, everything is positioned at the bottom of the screen. I attempted to use .scaleBy(), but unfortunately, that didn't change anything.
Could somebody please provide guidance on how to properly adjust the positioning in CGContext to align with SwiftUI's coordinate system and how to make a preview work?

To change the coordinate system so that the origin is at the top left, see this answer. Just translate the context up, and flip vertically.
This will also flip the SwiftUI view, so you should flip it back using .scaleEffect(y: -1).
Finally, if you want the GridView to take up all the available space like it does in an actual app, you should set its frame to the size of the PDF page.
(Actually, if you make the table take up all the available space, flipping the coordinate system is no longer necessary)
pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
let renderer = ImageRenderer(
    content: GridView(stats: stats).frame(width: 595.2, height: 841.8).scaleEffect(y: -1)
)
renderer.render { size, context in
    pdf.translateBy(x: 0, y: 841.8)
    pdf.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
    context(pdf)
}
pdf.endPDFPage()

Here is the result as viewed by Preview.app on macOS:


Xcode Preview only supports SwiftUI View, UIView, and UIViewController. A "PDF file" is none of those things. While you can convert it to an image and show it in an Image, I prefer using a PDFView from PDFKit:
import PDFKit

#Preview {
    let exportView = ExportImagesView()
    let url = exportView.render()
    let pdfView = PDFView()
    pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    return pdfView
}


Yeah, everything worked as described. I wish there is a way to award additional points on helpful answers like this. Thanks a bunch :)
